# What are external factors which can influence the clarity or early-prevailance of a person's earliest memory/memories

Tags: memory

Are there any external factors (i.e. with less focus on the genetic make-up of the individual persons) which can, in let's say, an average human, generate earlier and perhaps more clear earliest memories?

I would be very interested in any non-retrospective research in this area. That is: intervention studies, which I would guess probably need parents' approval.

So, I would be interested in both what types of events (I would naturally assume trauma is one, as well as perhaps general high emotional association in general, but I might be very wrong and would be equally interested in other ones), as well as perhaps if pedagogy or any other factor influence the ability to generate early childhood memories.

In particular, I am interested in whether or not this has anything to do with an early onset of self-conscience, or any other amenability between the individual and its environment.

To wrap up, and state my question briefly: can an early onset of childhood-memories be fostered?